# How to get the size of a user defined struct? (sizeof)

Tags: memory, rust, sizeof

I've got a structure with C representation:

```
struct Scard_IO_Request {
    proto: u32,
    pciLength: u32
}
```

when I want to ask the `sizeof` (like in C `sizeof()`) using:

`mem::sizeof<Scard_IO_Request>();`

I get compilation error:

```
"error: `sizeof` is a reserved keyword"
```

Why can't I use this `sizeof` function like in C? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For two reasons:

1. There is *no such function* as "`sizeof`", so the compiler is going to have a rather difficult time calling it.
2. That's not how you invoke generic functions.

If you check the documentation for `mem::size_of` (which you can find even if you [search for "sizeof"](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=sizeof)), you will see that it includes a [runnable example](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html#examples) which shows you how to call it.  For posterity, the example in question is:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::mem;
    assert_eq!(4, mem::size_of::<i32>());
}
```

In your specific case, you'd get the size of that structure using

```
mem::size_of::<Scard_IO_Request>()
```