# Do struct member names use more memory than if I use inherited class members?

Tags: class, memory, struct, rust

I'm trying to implement a class based format in Rust, which doesn't have classes or object-oriented concepts like inheritance.

Consider the following example:

```cpp
class Creature {
  int id;
  bool alive
};

class Human: public Creature {
  int salary;
};

class Dog: public Creature {
  bool has_fur;
};
```

If I want to implement the same structure in Rust I would do something like this:

```rust
struct Human {
    id: i32,
    alive: bool,
    salary: i32,
}

struct Dog {
    id: i32,
    alive: bool,
    has_fur: bool,
}
```

Will the duplicated structs make the application require more memory than if they were written in C++ and inherited from a base class (or maybe used prototypes in JavaScript)? The application will hold millions of objects.

I guess it will be a lot of duplicated member names in the code, which is maybe a problem in itself. But how would you translate the data structure in Rust (with the least memory implication as possible)? Or is this the way to go?

Comment: See [How to get the size of a user defined struct? (sizeof)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36664327/155423) and you can tell yourself what the size of each is.

Comment: Either in C++, in Rust or in whatever language you want, the information must be stored somewhere. You cannot have that for free.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios but in C++ and Rust the information is not saved in the executables.

Comment: Why not create `Creature` and have `Human` contain a variable of type `Creature`?

Comment: @Shepmaster that would be a good idea if the inheritance tree wasn't so deep. In the real project it's not uncommon with 7-10 inheritance levels (don't blame me, it's a standardized file format I'm implementing). And to access a member of the base struct would be really cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does the following: Each `Human` occupies some sufficiently many bytes to store `id`, `alive`, `salary` -- *in that order* (if you do not use any packing attributes (see [Force C++ structure to pack tightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092415/force-c-structure-to-pack-tightly))). For memory alignment, the struct fields may be padded, so they actually might occupy some bytes more than you expect.

Similarily for `Dog`.

Inheriting from a common base class reduces code, but - as you wrote it - does not save memory.

In Rust, each `Human` occupies sufficiently many bytes to store the fields, but Rust is - without [memory layout attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#representations) - allowed to reorder fields to save memory.

Repeating `id` and `alive` in two different structs makes code a bit more repetitive, but will not consume more bytes.

Comment: *but will not consume more bytes* — and based on your logic it might even *reduce* the size in comparison.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Type information is not kept at runtime, therefore `struct`s are free to create.